# Just started python and working through Automate The Boring Stuff with Python. Any recommendations on cleaning my code?

Tags: python-3.x

New here at stackoverflow. I'm learning python right now and picked up the book Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. Need some recommendations or tips on how to clean up my code. Here is one of the small projects from the book:

Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. If number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value. If number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1. Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps calling collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.

The output of this program could look something like this:

```
Enter number:
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Here's the code I came up with. Any recommendations on cleaning up the code or is this good enough? Thank you all!

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0: # Even numbers
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1: # Odd numbers
        result = 3 * number + 1
        print(result)
        return result

while True: # Made a loop until a number is entered
    try:
        n = input("Enter a random number: ")
        while n != 1:
            n = collatz(int(n))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter numbers only.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `else` in the place of `elif` , it will give same reasult.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized for readability and usage, not on performance.

```
def collatz(number):
    print(n)
    return number // 2 if number % 2 == 0 else 3 * number + 1
    
while True: # Made a loop until a number is entered
    try:
        n = input("Enter a random number: ")
        while n != 1: n = collatz(int(n))
        break
    except ValueError: print("Enter numbers only.")
```